# cannot load kernel object file adadio.ko

Tags: kernel

We are running Ubuntu 2.6.31-11. The computer was running a program to read from an analog-to-digital conversion board called the ADADIO by General Standards Corp. The windows environment was acting sporadically so we reset the platform. After rebooting the computer, we could no longer run the file that reads from the ADADIO board. The error message "cannot load adadio.ko" is displayed. We replaced the ADADIO driver board; so, we believe this is a software issue / operating system issue associated with a forced reset.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the driver yet?
Download the adadio.tar.gz file and follow the steps from this manual, when you want to try this opportunity:
http://www.generalstandards.com/driver-manuals/adadio_linux_driver_user_manual.pdf

I have no experience with this ADADIO, but I googled this up for you. Hopefully I can help!